# Angular 6 RXJS Import Syntax?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

I'm migrating an Angular 5 app to the latest CLI and Angular 6 RC and all of my Observable imports are broken. I see that Angular 6 changes the way the imports work, but I can't find any definite reference as to how the syntax works.

I had this in 5 and it worked fine:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Now with the new syntax I see that

```
import { Observable, Subject, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The first two lines compile, but I can't figure out how to get catch and throw for example. .map() also throws a build error when used in code.

Anybody have a reference to how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you ask for, but you need to refactor the code itself, if you haven't already done. There is the new `pipe` syntax. Something like e.g. `yourObservable$.pipe(map(val => val * 2)).subscribe()`. So with this kind of import you won't use `yourObservable$.map(blah)`. Here's some reference: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [rxjs 5.5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), `catch` has been renamed to `catchError` function to avoid name clash.

> Due to having operators available independent of an Observable, operator names cannot conflict with JavaScript keyword restrictions. Therefore the names of the pipeable version of some operators have changed.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

For `throw` you can use `ErrorObservable`.

```
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
ErrorObservable.create(new Error("oops"));
```

**rxjs 6**

Instead of ErrorObservable use [throwError](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#observable-classes).

```
 import { throwError } from 'rxjs'
 throwError(new Error("oops"));
```

Also you will now have to pipe the operators instead of directly chaining them to the observable

Comment: throw has a new name now i.e. throwError and you can import it like so:

**import { throwError } from 'rxjs';**

Comment: Doesn't importing it from 'rxjs' bring over the whole module? What is the more specific path for the import?

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai not in the case of rxjs v6. Apparently they have been changed according to [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths)

Answer (score 11):

Pipes are what is required for operator(s) going forward.

version: rxjs 6.0.1

Example:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    observer.next('Hello')
}).pipe(map((val: any) => val.toUpperCase()))
  .subscribe((x: any) => addItem(x))


function addItem(val: any) {
    console.log('val', val);
}

//output - (In uppercase)
HELLO
```

Answer (score 6):

Run these 2 commands after running `ng update`. This should fix the rxjs imports:

1. `npm i -g rxjs-tslint`
2. `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json`

References:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint

Comment: How does one get `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate` into a PATH variable? After I run `npm i -g rxjs-tslint`, and then run `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate` I get `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 5):

Or if you want to keep using version `6.0.0` you do

`npm i --save rxjs-compat`

to add reverse compatibility

Comment: Looks like you can do ng upgrade now to get that added automatically (along with updating Angular project refs to latest version).

Comment: There is no `ng upgrade` command. `ng update` you mean, it doesn't add the package

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import like operators

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';
```