# Cannot use simple map?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhzGSHNhnbI&t=527s

And at 51:41 he uses map. But my code doesn't work. Why I can't use it? I get

> Property map does not exists on Observable `<Response>`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(public http:Http) { 
    console.log("Data service connected...");
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: `http.get()` returns a promise. Try `http.get().then((data) => res.json(data))`

Comment: i ge tthe same error but with `then` and res doesn't exist

Comment: gotta love this tutorials where nobody knows the answers

Comment: This should work. What version of angular are you using? It seems that in the newer ones they changed map import statement (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47096060/2610466).

Comment: i did exactly what he said npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64

Comment: You have version 6.0, while tutorial is on the version 4.0. They changed somethings around, and you can't use by default the observable operators by chaining them. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811177/angular-6-rxjs-import-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service code you provide is using angular 6 which has dependency of rxjs 6.

So from rxjs 6 onwards you have to use pipeable operators and import paths are modified. so please change the code as follows

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) { 
    console.log("Data service connected...");
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .pipe(
        map(res => res.json())
       );
  }
}
```

And one more recommendation please start using HttpClient Module instead of Http Module. So even you dont need to use map to get json response

Please check this [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-new-angular-httpclient-api-9e5c85fe3361) for httpClient Module