# how to import the merge and fromEvent operators to Angular 6, rxjs 6.2.0?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a project written on Angular 5 and rxjs 5.5.5. how to correctly import it into Angular 6, rxjs 6.2.0? I can just write 'import {Observable,of, from } from 'rxjs';', but then i have a problem with 'merge' and 'fromEvent'

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: With RxJS 6 you should use pipable operators, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: You can also install `rxjs-compat` for backwards compatibility but it's better to upgrade and use the RxJS 6 style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 RXJS Import Syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811177/angular-6-rxjs-import-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [migration document](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths).
Correct imports are:

```
import {
    Observable,
    fromEvent,
    merge
} from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: ok, but how can I solve the problem after that? `return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
      // Filter data
      this.filteredData = this._exampleDatabase.data.slice().filter((item: UserData) => {
        let searchStr = (item.name + item.color).toLowerCase();
        return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });`

Comment: [ts] Property 'merge' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: @senjust simply call `merge(...displayDataChanges).pipe(map());` instead of `Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map()`.

Comment: read the migration guide, link to section about converting to pipe syntax:  https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#pipe-syntax

Comment: Thanks, with marge I solved the problem. Tell me please how to be with fromEvent: `Observable.fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .debounceTime(150)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(() => {...});`  I try this way, but I have an error: `fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(debounceTime(150)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(() => {...}));`

Comment: pipe function takes varargs, so you have to separate them with comma and not chain them: `fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(debounceTime(150), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe`